# html 100%- (one line)

Tags: html, iframe, height

I'm trying to use html to set the height of an iframe to 100% (which I have successfully done), but I also added an extra line of text at the top, so it's ~16px too tall (which requires a scroll bar). Is there a way to change the iframe to display something like `height="100%-16"`?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), you would use the following: `height: calc(100% - 16px);`

Unfortunately, this method doesn't have *full* support across browsers: [reference here](http://caniuse.com/calc).

[**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8XBDD/)

Comment: This just squishes my iframe way smaller than it was originally. Here's my website that I'm trying to change it for: calendar.deltamu.com (I've changed it back, but you can see the sourcecode, try it for yourself, and see how it doesn't work quite right)

Comment: @derekantrican I made some tweaks and it worked on your website. I'd suggest looking at the example I posted

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain how you got it to work? (I'm fairly new to HTML). I tried replacing the `html= "100"` with the `html: calc(100% - 16px);` And it just squished it again. Also, I saw that you're using `div{}` instead of `<div>`. Is that a different language?

Comment: @derekantrican Yea, that's CSS. You could add it via the style attribute: `style="height: calc(100% - 16px);"`. That would easily work; however the element will be positioned at the top, therefore you need to use positioning as I did in my example and position it to the bottom of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to make the `<iframe>` fill the entire window except for the part with the text, use absolute positioning instead of setting specific dimensions:

```css
#my-frame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em; /* Whatever height you like */

    /* All the other ones are just distances from each side, not sizes */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This works for all elements and takes into account both border and padding.

Comment: Will this change based on different sized resolution monitors? (That's the main reason I'm using 100% as opposed to absolute dimensions)

Comment: @derekantrican: Yes. “Absolute positioning” is not the same as “absolute dimensions”.